# Offset tick labels to center between ticks on horizontal bar chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am creating a horizontal bar chart using Google charts and I want to position the horizontal axis tick labels between ticks (offset tick label to the right by half a tick). There is also no guarantee that each label will be the same number of characters. Is there any functionality to achieve this?

This is my function for creating the chart

```
function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["Performance", "Level", { role: "style" }],
                ["PL", 1.01, "#5aa66d"]
            ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                {
                    calc: function (dt, rowIndex) { return 'PL=' + (dt.getValue(rowIndex, 1)).toString()} ,
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation"
                },
                2]);

            var options = {
                width: 600,
                height: 100,
                bar: { groupWidth: "80%" },
                legend: { position: "none" },
                hAxis: {
                    minValue: 0,
                    maxValue: 3,
                    ticks: [
                        { v: 0, f: 'Col1' },
                        { v: 1, f: 'Col2' },
                        { v: 2, f: 'Col3' },
                        { v: 3, f: 'Col4' }
                    ]
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
```

This is the chart currently
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iudCu.jpg
 and this is what I want to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrUsh.jpg

EDIT:
For ideas, right before chart.draw I add an event listener and find all the text tags and modify the 'x' attribute to re-position the tick labels. This works, but it also affects the on-bar data label which is a problem.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
       var elements = document.getElementById("barchart_values").getElementsByTagName("text");
       for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
              elements[i].setAttribute('x', (Number(elements[i].getAttribute('x')) + (chart.getChartLayoutInterface().getBoundingBox('chartarea').width / 4 / 2))); //chart width / tick count / 2
                }
            });
```

Comment: @WhiteHat I don't think the answer you provided works in my case as the '0' tick label is still on the horiztonal axis when it should be shifted up half a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, we won't be able to offset the grid lines *and* use the `ticks` option.

let's offset the grid lines by making the major transparent and the minor visible.
we can also offset the baseline by setting to a negative value.

```
        baseline: -0.5,
        minorGridlines: {
            color: '#cccccc',
            count: 1
        },
        gridlines: {
            color: 'transparent',
            count: 4
        },
```

then, in order to have custom tick labels, we can use your original idea to change them manually.
just need a unique attribute to separate them from the bar labels.
here, the `text-anchor` attribute is used.

```
        if (elements[i].getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
            elements[i].textContent = 'Col' + parseInt(elements[i].textContent) + 1;
        }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Performance", "Level", { role: "style" }],
        ["PL", 1.01, "#5aa66d"]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: function (dt, rowIndex) { return 'PL=' + (dt.getValue(rowIndex, 1)).toString()} ,
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: "string",
        role: "annotation"
    }, 2]);

    var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 100,
        bar: { groupWidth: "80%" },
        legend: { position: "none" },
        hAxis: {
            baseline: -0.5,
            minorGridlines: {
                color: '#cccccc',
                count: 1
            },
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent',
                count: 4
            },
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 3,
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        var elements = document.getElementById("barchart_values").getElementsByTagName("text");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
                elements[i].textContent = 'Col' + (parseInt(elements[i].textContent) + 1);
            }
        }
    });

    chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart_values"></div>
```

the above will ensure all the labels remain visible, just simply moving them, could cause them to be pushed off the visible portion of the chart.

Comment: this does the job. I was unaware of hAxis.baseline thanks.